# Facebook Oauth 2.0 header format

Tags: facebook-oauth

I am having a native application in facebook. i would like to use oauth 2.0. Read that oauth header will contain timestamp, nounce, signature etc.. For google this can be generated with oauth playground. How to do the same in facebook.

Can anyone help me out with a good tutorial or can anyone say how the header format will be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is not expecting timestamp,nounce,signature in its oauth header.

I got the problem solved.